# Is it correct to say 'to be applying'?

Tags: verb-forms

> I am going **to apply** this concept.
>
> I am going **to applying** this concept.
>
> I am going **to be applying** this concept.

These are correct and mean the same?

Answer (score 2):

I am going to apply this concept is correct,
I am going to appling this concept is incorrect (you need 'be' before applying to make it future, OR removing 'going to' will make it present)
I am going to be applying this concept is also correct.

There is however, a difference between the first and last one. The first can be 'present' (not stictly now but in next minute/few seconds, is informal though) or future tense. The last one is strictly future.

Comment: It means 'going to be applying' can be the next-day , next-time etc but 'going to apply' means currently+the next day+the next time,etc

Comment: In reference to http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18772/to-hear-or-to-hearing , 'to hearing' is correct but then why not 'to applying'?

Comment: Could you please try to put your answer on this  question too: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/328911/170668
 
I'm puzzled with this question, i will be waiting for your answer

Answer (score 2):

> I am going to apply this concept.

This means that you will apply it at least once.

> I am going to be applying this concept.

This means that you will be applying it during a period of time, continuously or repeatedly.

As for *"I am going to applying this concept" it is altogether ungrammatical.

Comment: *"This means that you will apply it repeatedly, persistently, zealously"* - I have to disagree with that.  "I can't come to your party tomorrow, because I am going to be burying my grandfather" doesn't mean I am going to bury him repeatedly, persistently, or zealously.

Comment: I can't but agree and have to rethink it.

Comment: @Rompey refer:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18772/to-hear-or-to-hearing  , "To hearing" is grammatical then why not 'to applying'?Please explain

Comment: @AnubhavSingh: that's not "to hearing", that's "look forward to" + "hearing".

Comment: @AnubhavSingh: "To look forward to something (a noun, or a verb+ing)" is a set phrase which doesn't need any explanation.